# regex needed to match anything between two paragraph

Tags: regex

Please need a regular expression to match anything that is between :

```
<a name="RcpIndicTherap">4.1. Indications thérapeutiques</a>
```

and

```
<a name="RcpPosoAdmin">4.2. Posologie et mode d'administration</a>
```

in this html code :

```
<p class="AmmAnnexeTitre2"><a name="RcpIndicTherap">4.1. Indications thérapeutiques</a></p>
<p class=AmmCorpsTexte><u>Hypertension</u></p>
<p class=AmmCorpsTexte>Traitement de l’hypertension artérielle essentielle chez l’adulte.</p>
<p class=AmmCorpsTexte><u>Prévention cardiovasculaire</u></p>
<p class=AmmCorpsTexte>Réduction de la morbidité cardiovasculaire chez les adultes présentant :</p>
<p class=AmmListePuces1><span style='font-family:Symbol'>·<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>         </span></span>une maladie cardiovasculaire athérothrombotique connue (antécédents de coronaropathie, d’accident vasculaire cérébral, ou d’artériopathie périphérique) ou</p>
<p class=AmmListePuces1><span style='font-family:Symbol'>·<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>         </span></span>un diabète de type 2 avec une atteinte d’organe cible documentée.</p>
<p class="AmmAnnexeTitre2"><a name="RcpPosoAdmin">4.2. Posologie et mode d'administration</a></p>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You'll have better results if you post what you have tried so far and what results you have had, rather than simply asking for the solution.  Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

Just use `</a>.*<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

With perl, "man perlre". The "s" modifier change "." to match any character, even newline.

"*?" modify "*" so that the matched string will be as short as possible.

```
perl -e 'while(<STDIN>){$txt.=$_;} while($txt=~/<\/a>(.*?)<a/sg){print"I found ------$1-------\n";}' < your_file.html
```